# SPI between Master arduino and Slave arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, sd-card, rfid

How can I send the string from Slave SPI to Master SPI?

I want to write code in Bare Metal.

The problem which I am facing is I can't make out what will be my blocking function in Master SPI code when receiving data from slave SPI.

As my SPIF bit is cleared in MAster code as soon as I shift out SPDR register from master to receive byte which is coming from the slave.

```
#define spi_data_reg SPDR     
//Naster read byte function
    uint8_t MA_SPI0_read_byte()
    {    
        spi_port &= ~(1<<SS);
        spi_data_reg = 0;
        while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));                  //Wait until transmission complete
        return(spi_data_reg);                                 //Return received data
       spi_port |= (1<<SS);
    }
    
    //Slave send byte function
    void SL_SPI0_send_byte(uint8_t data)
    {
        spi_data_direc=(1<<MISO);   //MISO as OUTPUT
        spi_data_reg = data;
        while(!(SPSR &(1<<SPIF)));
    }
```

Comment: At first: `spi_port |= (1<<SS);` after the return wil not work. You'll never reach the line. Why do you initialize `spi_data_reg = 0;`? Have you set the master to input like `spi_data_direc=(1<<MISO);` elsewhere? I did not yet programmed SPI communications with the low level api, so I do not know if one of these could be the problem. But as no one else repsonded ... Just some ideas; better than nothing.

Comment: As far as I understand SPI communication, Slave cannot send data to Master without Master initiating the communication. Typically, Master sends a dummy data so that it can receive a response from Slave. So Master needs to know how many bytes to receive and send dummy data to Slave as many times to get the response.